# UITableview didSelectRowAtIndexPath supercedes double tap gesture by UITapGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer

I've set up a UITableView with a double-tap UITapGestureRecognizer.  But attempts to double-tap a cell by the user just launches didSelectRowAtIndexPath twice.  Are these two supposed to work together?

(i'm aware i could use a single tap gesture recognizer in place of the built-in behavior of didSelectRowAtIndexPath, but here's the problem with that: the cell also has a button that I can't press anymore when i add the single tap gesture recognizer.  Also, I've seen examples on SO of users building double tap functionality into didSelectRowAtIndexPath, but isn't that a bit too much of a hack?)

Comment: I wanted a similar feature. Even after setting `cancelsTouchesInView` and `delaysTouchesBegan` I couldn't invoke the double tap handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ***can*** use a *single*-tap gesture recognizer in place of `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, even if there is a button in the cell. You just need to check if the touch location is inside the `UIButton`'s view or not in order to handle both cases. Hope that Helps!

Comment: right- your talking about setting the delegate and then implementing gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch: or gestureRecognizerShouldBegin.  Thanks for the reminder.  I'll try to get this working and then accept as the answer.  Also, it sounds like your saying you agree that the scenario I have in the original question above won't work?

Comment: Yes, as the method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` will intercept the touch event as it has priority over the gesture recognizer, and since you most likely have it implemented, the gesture recognizer will never get called.

Comment: Actually, I haven't tested it thoroughly but I'm seeing that the properties delaysTouchesBegan and cancelsTouchesInView set to YES for the gesture recognizer are giving me the desired behavior.

Answer (score 12):

More info about Kris' answer:

- cancelsTouchesInView
- delaysTouchesBegan
- delaysTouchesEnded

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html

In my case I had a problem when adding 2 tap gestures to a `UIImageView` that was on a custom `UITableViewCell`. What happened was the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` was called when you tap/double tap on the `UIImageView`. When I had only one tap gesture, the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` was not called (and for me, that was the right behavior.

To prevent the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` from being called when using two tap gestures (single/double tap), I added this code to the first tap gesture (the single one):

```
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = YES;
tapGesture.delaysTouchesBegan = YES;
```

After this change, a tap/double on the `UIImageView` (on top of the custom cell) did not trigger the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

Answer (score 5):

Looks like I can get didSelectRowAtIndexPath and the double tap gesture recognizer to play together nicely using the delaysTouchesBegan and cancelsTouchesInView properties of the gesture recognizer.

The other option described by @MSgambel seems to work equally well.

Answer (score 1):

I tested the "delayTouchesBegan" method with double taps but I found that the single tap received by the table is then delayed, making the table interaction less responsive to the user, and perhaps annoying.

My solution is a bit pedestrian but I use a timer to detect taps in method didSelectRowAtIndexPath. I record the tap count of "1" for the first tap, and if the user does not tap again with 0.2 seconds it displays the item selected. If the user tapped within 0.2 seconds for tap count "2" then I display another item (an action sheet). I reset the tap count each time.

This method uses more code, but provides quick response from the interface and the user does not need to know what is happening behind the scenes - just that the UI is responsive.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'm skeptical about the idea of creating a timer to handle this, but a creative idea nonetheless. Thanks!

Comment: The delay is imo way too long when using the built-in recognizer, so I tend to agree the user will like the responsiveness this provides more, even though it is a bit hacky behind the scenes.